# `gatsby build` works locally, but not on netlify CMS

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

i'm deploying a prototype to netlify cms to experiment with the blog/markdown functionality that netlify cms offers. however, my build has failed (despite `gatsby build` working locally). i've seen that `exit code 127` is quite a common error, but i've cleared both my gatsby/netlify cache, tried switching to `npm run build` to get a more comprehensive list of errors (didn't work, just kept printing `> blog@1.0.0 build > npm run build` in my terminal). i'm not sure if this might be due to dependency issues as there were plugins that i had to install with `--legacy-peer-deps`.

Here's my deploy log and a link to my repo: https://github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings. Would appreciate any help!

```
12:02:11 PM: Build ready to start
12:08:45 PM: build-image version: 7b53c5fc4445e3ec99d3949e5d1174a8c5be4f16
12:08:45 PM: build-image tag: v3.7.2
12:08:45 PM: buildbot version: a8df6d1263bb5bcc16f7b4ebb8e9a6cb904cfa8a
12:08:45 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
12:08:45 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
12:08:45 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
12:08:46 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
12:08:46 PM: git clone https://github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings
12:09:02 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
12:09:04 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
12:09:05 PM: Starting build script
12:09:05 PM: Installing dependencies
12:09:05 PM: Python version set to 2.7
12:09:06 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
12:09:07 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
12:09:07 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
12:09:07 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
12:09:07 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
12:09:08 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
12:09:08 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
12:09:08 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
12:09:08 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
12:09:09 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:09:09 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:09:09 PM: Installing missing commands
12:09:09 PM: Verify run directory
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:09:10 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
12:09:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ❯ Version
12:09:10 PM:   @netlify/build 11.3.2
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ❯ Flags
12:09:10 PM:   deployId: 608a2fc31e2066000802ecfa
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ❯ Current directory
12:09:10 PM:   /opt/build/repo
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ❯ Config file
12:09:10 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ❯ Context
12:09:10 PM:   production
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:09:10 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
12:09:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: $ gatsby build
12:09:10 PM: bash: gatsby: command not found
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:09:10 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
12:09:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM:   Error message
12:09:10 PM:   Command failed with exit code 127: gatsby build
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM:   Error location
12:09:10 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:09:10 PM:   gatsby build
12:09:10 PM: ​
12:09:10 PM:   Resolved config
12:09:10 PM:   build:
12:09:10 PM:     command: gatsby build
12:09:10 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:09:10 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
12:09:11 PM: Caching artifacts
12:09:11 PM: Started saving build plugins
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving build plugins
12:09:11 PM: Started saving pip cache
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving pip cache
12:09:11 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
12:09:11 PM: Started saving go dependencies
12:09:11 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
12:09:13 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:09:13 PM: Creating deploy upload records
12:09:13 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:09:13 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:09:13 PM: Finished processing build request in 28.232494224s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is generally related to the mismatching of dependencies between your local environment and your Netlify environment causing this output.

Try changing your [`package.json`](https://github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings/blob/main/blog/package.json#L7) (and if so, in your Netlify's dashboard) command to:

```
"build": "npm run build",
```

If you see locally a lot of warnings about peer-dependencies, then you will need to install them, as the [migration guide shows](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/).

Another workaround that might be helpful for you, is to fix your Node versions using the `.nvmrc` file. Run:

```
node -v > .nvmrc
```

This will create a `.nvmrc` file in the root of your project with the Node version (`node -v`) in it. Netlify when it's building your site will use that file to set the Node environment as the [docs](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-and-javascript) point out. It's very useful when trying to debug the origin of some issues.

In addition, don't upload (remove it as soon as possible and ignore it in the `.gitignore`) the [`.cache`](https://github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings/tree/main/blog/.cache) folder from your repo. You don't want to keep it and it will save you time when pulling/pushing things from your repo (and potentially avoiding conflicts if someone else works in your project).

Comment: omg i'd totally forgot about changing the build command on netlify's dashboard! turned out to be an issue with the location of my base repo. thanks again!